# Remove everything in string up to last forward slash

Tags: regex, r

I have a string like this:

```
"vehicles/vehicle_type/filename.csv"
```

I just want to be left with:

```
"filename.csv"
```

I have tried this:

```
sub('/^(.*[\\\/])/', "", the_string)
```

But get an "unrecognized escape in character string" error

Comment: Don't know `r`, but if you really want to replace, use a sub with this `/^(?:[^\/]*\/)+/`. If you just want to match at the end use this `/[^\/]+$/`.

Answer (score 38):

To grab the end of a file path, you could use simply `basename()`.

```
x <- "vehicles/vehicle_type/filename.csv"
basename(x)
# [1] "filename.csv"
```

Or if you'd like to continue using regex, adjust your `sub()` call to

```
sub(".*/", "", x)
# [1] "filename.csv"
```

`.*` removes everything, so `.*/` removes everything up to and including the final `/` (because the previous one was included in the "everything").

Comment: Just note that `basename` will only work on characters, so depending on how your paths were read into R, you might have to do `basename(as.character(x))`. Sometimes when a column contains path names, R reads them as factors instead.

Comment: elegant and useful solution!!