# R: How to match a forward-slash in a regular expression?

Tags: r, regex, path

How do I match on a forward slash `/` in a regular expression in R?

As demonstrated in the example below, I am trying to search for .csv files in a subdirectory and my attempts to use a literal `/` are failing. Looking for a modification to my regex in base R, not a function that does this for me.

#### Example subdirectory

```r
# Create subdirectory in current working directory with two .csv files
# - remember to delete these later or they'll stay in your current working directory!
dir.create(path = "example")
write.csv(data.frame(x1 = letters), file = "example/example1.csv")
write.csv(data.frame(x2 = 1:20), file = "example/example2.csv")
```

#### Get relative paths of all .csv files in the `example` subdirectory

```r
# This works for the example, but could mistakenly return paths to other files based on:
# (a) file name: foo/example1.csv
# (b) subdirectory name: example_wrong/foo.csv
list.files(pattern = "example.*csv", recursive = TRUE)
#> [1] "example/example1.csv" "example/example2.csv"

# This fixes issue (a) but doesn't fix issue (b)
list.files(pattern = "^example.*?\\.csv$", recursive = TRUE)
#> [1] "example/example1.csv" "example/example2.csv"

# Adding / to the end of `example` guarantees we get the correct subdirectory

# Doesn't work: / is special regex and not escaped
list.files(pattern = "^example/.*?\\.csv$", recursive = TRUE)

# Doesn't work: escapes / but throws error
list.files(pattern = "^example\/.*?\\.csv$", recursive = TRUE)

# Doesn't work: even with the \\ escaping in R!
list.files(pattern = "^example\\/.*?\\.csv$", recursive = TRUE)
```

Some of the solutions above work with [regex tools](https://regex101.com/) but not in R. I've checked SO for solutions (most related below) but none seem to apply:

[Escaping a forward slash in a regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6076229/escaping-a-forward-slash-in-a-regular-expression)

[Regex string does not start or end (or both) with forward slash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62067528/regex-string-does-not-start-or-end-or-both-with-forward-slash)

[Reading multiple csv files from a folder with R using regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47189714/reading-multiple-csv-files-from-a-folder-with-r-using-regex)

Comment: I think you can do this with `dir_ls` from `{fs}` package. This function as well as other functions from this package really provides a bunch of useful options to work with paths in R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `pattern` argument is only used for matching file (or directory) names, not the full path they are on (even when `recursive` and `full.names` are set to `TRUE`). That's why your last approach doesn't work even though it is the correct way to match `/` in a regular expression. You can get the correct file names by specifying `path` and setting `full.names` to `TRUE`.

```r
list.files(path='example', pattern='\\.csv$', full.names=T)
```

Comment: Note: you can also just post-process with e.g. `gsub` and `basename()` as found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36683359/remove-everything-in-string-up-to-last-forward-slash